# Vim :find command deadlock

Tags: vim

When I use the `:find` command followed by the first letters of a file name and then hit tab (to get autocompletion), VIM locks, and I have to shut down and start over.

For instance, I write

```
:find nam
```

and then I hit tab. VIM write three dots after:

```
:find nam...
```

and then stops working. Indefinitely. This happens when I am on the root directory of a project I'm working on. This directory has the following sub-folders:

```
.git/
.idea/
.sass-cache/
.tmp/
app/
node_modules/
phone/
test/
```

And these files:

```
.bowerrc
.gitattributes
.gitignore
.jshintrc
Gruntfile.js
Readme.md
bower.json
karma.conf.js
npm-debug.log
package.json
todo.txt
```

If I cd to the app directory and try the same command, when I hit tab the autocompletion works perfectly.

I'm running VIM on Windows. I have set the path variable to `.,,**` on my _vimrc file (`set path=.,,**`).

Well, does anyone have any idea about what is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, `:find` uses a wasteful depth-first strategy that makes it dig into *every* directory and *every* sub-directory before going to the next directory at the same level.

Earlier versions of npm were notorious for the potential depth of the `node_module` directory structure so it's very likely that your `node_modules` directory acts as a trap, here.

Since you probably don't want to edit anything in `node_modules` I suggest you add it to your `wildignore` option:

```
set wildignore+=*/node_modules/*
```

---

Also, `**` in `set path=.,,**` implies `,,` so you could simplify that value to `.,**`.